# Keras model with Tensorflow Hub does not give same result when save/restore

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-hub

I have a Keras model that uses a Tensorflow hub layer. However the model does not give the same predictions between the original and the restored model.

My Keras model :

```py
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/remote_sensing/eurosat-resnet50/1", tags=['train'], input_shape=(64,64,3))

original_model = Sequential()
original_model.add(hub_layer)
original_model add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
original_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

original_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = original_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=100)

img_batch = ... # Image batch of shape (32, 64, 64, 3)
original_model.predict(img_batch)
```

Original model Output :

```
Out[1] : array([[0.803754  ],
               [0.2758078 ],
               ...
               [0.26074764],
               [0.6190501 ]]
```

When the model is saved and restored the predictions are not the same:

```py
orignial_model.save("model.hd5")

restored_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.hd5", custom_objects={'KerasLayer': hub.KerasLayer})

restored_model.predict(img_batch) # The image batch used is exactly the same as before
```

Output restored model :

```
Out[2] : array([[0.9999999 ],
                [1.        ],
                ...
                [1.        ],
                [1.        ]]
```

The results are not the same as the original model.

I tried the same experiment but without the Tensorflow layer and the problem did not appear. So I guess the problem comes from this Tensorflow hub layer.

I also tried to compare the configuration of the 2 models and they are identical :

```py
original_model.get_config() == restored_model.get_config() # Return true
```

I also compared the weights of the 2 models and they are identical.

Version :

- Tensorflow : 2.0.0
- Keras : 2.3.1
- Tensorflow Hub : 0.8.0
- Python : 3.7.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the source of the problem but I found an alternative solution.

This solution consists in removing the tensorflow hub layer from the model. The transformation done by this layer can then be done outside like this:

```
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/remote_sensing/eurosat-resnet50/1", tags=['train'], input_shape=(64,64,3))

original_model = Sequential()
original_model.add(Input(2048))
original_model add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
original_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

original_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

X_transformed = hub_layer(X)

history = original_model.fit(X_transformed, y, epochs=100)
```

By doing this, the model predictions between the original model and the restored model are identical.